# Highcharts data label vertical alignment - bug

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

Im facing an issue with highcharts js library where im trying to put the value of the point inside the shape.
for this im using `inside: true, verticalAlign: 'middle'` for data label which seem to work just fine but whenever the point is at the start or at the end of the chart the label does not align correctly.
I have already tried offset and padding but its for the whole axis not the label.
I would really appreciate any suggestion, clues or solutions

http://jsfiddle.net/Andam/6km2fw31/1/
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highcharts tries to position data labels on a plot area due to default `justify` option for overflow. As a solution change overflow to `allow`.

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  verticalAlign: 'middle',
    crop: false,
    overflow: 'allow'
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f2r7hL3j/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels.overflow